# What's the point of re-exporting * and { default } in zustand.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, zustand

I am trying to read and understand the source code of [`zustand`](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) and encountered this code in [`index.ts`](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/src/index.ts)

```
export * from './vanilla'
export * from './react'
export { default as createStore } from './vanilla'
export { default } from './react'
```

What's the point of line 3 and 4? I thought that it might be to enable importing functions in both manners, this way

```
import create from 'zustand'
```

and this way

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
```

but the second `import` throws the error:

```
Module '"zustand"' has no exported member 'create'. Did you mean to use 'import create from "zustand"' instead?
```

EDIT: I am aware of what I need to do to correctly import the create function. I just don't understand why the `index.ts` needs line 3 and 4. What are the effects of that.

Comment: `import { create } from 'zustand'` needs to be `import { createStore } from 'zustand'`. Or if you want to rename it, `import { createStore as create } from 'zustand'`

Comment: @NicholasTower I am actually interested in the `create` function as described [here](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/src/react.ts#L79). I am just not entirely sure what the point of line 3 and 4 of `index.ts` are.

Comment: `create` is exported as `default` from `./react`. And in `index`, it is imported from `./react` and re-exported as `default` too. This is what makes `import create from 'zustand'` work. The line above it makes `import { createStore } from 'zustand'` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this does:

```
export { default as createStore } from './vanilla'
```

is - it takes the default export from that file, and in *this* file, exports it under the name `createStore`.

What this does:

```
export { default } from './react'
```

is - it takes the default export from that file, and in this file, exports it as default.

Without lines 3 and 4, the above would not occur - neither default export from vanilla nor react would be re-exported here. (doing `export * from` only re-exports *named* exports)

`create` is not a named export in the `vanilla` nor `react` files, and neither lines 3 nor 4 create an export named `create`, so `import { create } from 'zustand'` (which tries to retrieve the export named `create`) isn't permitted.

When consuming zustand, to import vanilla's default export, you'd need to do

```
import { createStore } from 'zustand';
// this can be renamed when importing with `as` if desired
```

To import React's default export, you'd need to do

```
import create from 'zustand';
// this can be named whatever you want, since it's a default import
```

If lines 3 and 4 didn't exist, neither of those two above snippets would work, because the default exports from `react` and `vanilla` wouldn't be re-exported.